# Why I have access violation at address x?

Tags: delphi

I'm a newbie in Delphi. I want to instantiate a class from another unit and I can't.

This is my **Main.pas** unit:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.RegularExpressions,
  System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Files, Records;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    edRoutes: TEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    edFilename: TEdit;
    {...}
    lData: TLabel;
    eDate: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  //routes: TArray<TRoute>;
  readFile: TReadFile;
  stFilename: String;
  stText: String;
  sDate: String;
  RegExp: TRegEx;
  Match: TMatch;

begin
  stFilename := edFilename.Text;
  readFile := readFile.Create(stFilename);
  try
    readFile.LoadFile();
    stText := readFile.getText();
    Memo1.Text := stText;
    RegExp.Create('Día de entrega :    (?<date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})');
    if Regexp.IsMatch(stText) then
      begin
        Match := Regexp.Match(stText);
        sDate := Match.Groups['date'].Value;
        eDate.Text := sDate.Replace('.', '/');
      end;
  finally
    readFile.Free;
  end;
end;

{...}

end.
```

And this my **Files.pas** unit:

```
unit Files;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, Vcl.Dialogs,
  System.RegularExpressions, System.Variants, System.Classes;

  type
    TReadFile = class(TObject)
    var
      stFilename: String;
      stText: String;
    private
    public
      constructor Create(const Filename: String);
      procedure LoadFile();
      function getDate(): String;
      function getText(): String;
    end;

  var
    readFile: TReadFile;

implementation

constructor TReadFile.Create(const Filename: String);
begin
    self.stFilename := Filename;
    self.stText := '';
end;

{...}

end.
```

I think it is because the variables of the *Files.pas* are not initialized, but I didn't find any solution around the web.

Line `readFile := readFile.Create(stFilename);` in **Main.pas** invoke the error. I ensure that stFilename is not **nil**, and I know that the error is due to line `self.stFilename := Filename;` in the second unit (*Files.pas*).

I've attempted to overload Create method, but it doesn't work.

I've also attempted to change the visibility but it doesn't work too.

This post is my last chance. :/

Comment: In case you haven't got the drift from the answers, in Delphi you need to invoke the constructor for the class, i.e. TReadFile.Create, **not** the constructor of an instance of the class.  Calling the constructor of the class, TReadFile.Create, returns an instance of it which you can then assign to a variable, such as your readFile.  The way you've declared it, Delphi initializes readFile to Nil, which is why trying to invoke its methids produces an AV.

Answer (score 3):

```
  readFile := readFile.Create(stFilename);
```

should be

```
  readFile := TReadFile.Create(stFilename);
```

When invoked on a *class*, a constructor allocates memory for a new object of this type, initializes all fields to zero, and runs the actual constructor on this new object. A pointer to the new object is returned. This is how you create objects in Delphi.

On the other hand, you try to invoke the constructor on an *object* (class instance). That will simply run the constructor's code on that instance. However, your `readFile` variable doesn't point to a valid object instance at the time when you run this code. Being an uninitialized local variable of a non-managed type, it can be any address. Hence you try to invoke a method using an essentially random pointer, which eventually causes your AV.

This is all [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Constructors).

Answer (score 3):

It's really simple. At Main.pas you must create a new instance of the TReadFile class.

In order to do so, you call TReadFile.Create. Therefore replace the line

```
readfile := readfile.Create(stFileName);
```

with

```
readfile := TReadFile.Create(stFileName);
```